# How can I change the capitalization of the project directory VS Code passes when debugging?

Tags: visual-studio-code, next.js

I'm running a Next.JS project in VS Code. My `launch.json` has the following configuration:

```
{
    // ...
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Frontend: Dev Server",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "run-script",
                "dev",
                "--preserve-symlinks", // To debug linked
            ],
            "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "type": "node",
            
        }
    ],
}
```

When I run this configuration from VS Code, I get an error like the following:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd run-script dev --preserve-symlinks
> web-client@0.1.0 dev
> next dev -p 5555
warn  - Invalid casing detected for project dir, received c:\etcetc actual path C:\etcetc, see more info here https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/invalid-project-dir-casing
```

I know that I want VS Code to pass in the drive letter in upper case instead of lower case, but I don't see any option to set that and I tried opening the project using `code C:\etcetc` directly.

How can I change the capitalization of the directory that VS Code applies to the launch configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Add a current working directory to your `launch.json` configuration:

```
{
    // ...
    "configurations": [
        {
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "name": "Frontend: Dev Server",
            // ...
        }
    ]
}
```

This passed an upper case drive letter to Node for me. You may also want to check that VS Code is opening the folder with the right case, i.e. `node C:\etcetc`.

If you still have casing errors, try deleting the `.next` directory.